# MS Excel 365 : Comma Delimited data to rows for multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, power-query

I've comma delimited values in two columns like in the image here.

Main data:

[image: Main Data]]

After using power query and splitting them in rows , I'm getting data as:

[image: Tabular Data]]

But the expected data format is:

[image: Expected Data]]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Enumetare splitted values for both columns values (i.e. `'bob,alex'` is splitted to `'1','bob'` and `'2','alex'`), then join and order them by `(template, number)`. The `number` column, if you'll not find the way to exclude it from output, may be hidden.

Comment: @Akina Can you please share a working solution , if possible

Comment: I do not use Power Query. i know how to do it using pure SQL...

Comment: Look at [this article](http://excel-inside.pro/blog/2015/11/05/absolute-and-relative-references-in-power-query/). It describes how to access to the field of previous record. Now.. We split a column, then index it, then we create new column ([New]), where we compare [Template] for current and previous records, if they are equal, we set new column to [previous value+1], if not, we set it to [1]. Then we do the same with another column (split, index, add column). And the last - we take this 2 results and combine them by [Template1]=[Template2] and [New1]=[New2]. Now we must obtain desured result.